# Why we have to synthesize?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I'm new to i phone I want to know why we have to synthesize.

Comment: Whatever you want to synthesize is not gonna synthesize itself.

Comment: I don't synthesize, I accessorize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use `@synthesize`, but if you don't then you are responsible to write the setter and getter methods for that property.

Answer (score 1):

The @synthesize directive automatically generates the setters and getters for us,

Accessors will only be generated if they don't already exist, so feel free to specify @synthesize for a property, then implement your custom getter or setter if you want. The compiler will fill in whichever method is missing.

check this link: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/