# Is there an actual reason why do we have to use @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c

So I use the `@property` key in my header file.

*If* I do that, I should use the `@synthesize` key in my implementation, right? But I wonder, is there an actual *reason* I have to do that? I'm just wondering why isn't writing `@property` in the header just about enough for the to code know my intentions (having the get/set methods automagically generated).

Sure, according to [Why we have to synthesize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966756/why-we-have-to-synthesize) we write `@synthesize` to generate the get/set methods. But my question is about *why isn't `@property` in the header just enough for this*?
 I ask because whenever I write `@property` in my header, I immediately go to the implementation and write `@synthesize`. So for me, the only reason `@synthesize` is used is to complement the `@property` keyword. Which seems rather redundant, and makes me assume that `@synthesize` wouldn't exist if it wasn't because it *has other uses*.  What are those other uses?

Comment: Actually in the next iteration of Xcode and LLVM you won't need to type synthesize. it will automatically synthesize your properties as I understand it.

Comment: @RyanPoolos: Did they mention why are they going to make such change?

Comment: In the version of Xcode being released along with ios 6, it is no longer required to use '@synthesize' because they are upgrading the language to include 'synthesize by default' and many other features that reduce the amount of code required.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_object_literals_subscripting You can find more information here about why, what, and other changes.

Comment: @RyanPoolos But what if you only want a getter but no setter for example. In this case, you wouldn't use `@synthesize` at all, you'd write your own getter. How could you do that if it will be auto-generated?

Comment: @Hassan, it will only generate accessors that you haven't manually written, which is the same way `@synthesize` behaves today.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Yes, but if I write a getter, and `@synthesize` is added automatically, it will also generate a setter.

Comment: don't forget, for each `@property` you should use either `@syntesize`  or `@dynamic` declaration in your `.m` file. what you are using depends on you, and this is why the `@property` definition does not decide it instead of you.

Comment: @Hassan you can specify a `@property` as readonly and still use `@synthesize` if you just want a getter.

Comment: Also note that you can always suppress automatic synthesize with `@dynamic`. This was one of those really obvious changes to clang that simplifies the common case without imposing restrictions on the more unusual cases.

Comment: if you don't want to use neither declarations, you have to write the setter and/or the getter manually for your `@property`. (the setter is not needed if the `@property` is `readonly`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@synthesize` does two things. It generates the getter/setter pair and it creates the iVar for the property.

Of these two things, I think the iVar creation is the key to when I use `@synthesize` and when I don't. When create properties for members that are not internally stored as iVars, then (obviously) I don't use `@synthesize`.

<strike>The upcoming auto synthesize feature is not going to be of much help. I always name my iVars with a leading '_', and so I will still need to explicitly synthesize them.</strike>

**See @AndrewMadsen link**: it looks like '_' prefix auto synthesize will generate the iVars.

W00t! Needless to say, I'm much more excited about auto synthesize now!!

Comment: Actually, auto synthesize uses underscore prefixed ivar names by default. You have to explicitly `@synthesize` if you want to synthesize/use *non*-prefixed ivars.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen do you have a source for that?

Comment: also note that you could use `@dynamic` and add the methods yourself, i think not automagically assuming `@synthesize` is better as you can then have readonly properties that are literally readonly via @dynamic (only implementing the getter) or just in general the flexibility of implementing these properties the two different ways helps

Answer (score 0):

As it generates the getters and setters for the instance variables, both to use internally and to use from outside your class, the real magic is found in the setter, as it does the following:

```
- (void)setValue: (id)newValue
{
    if (value != newValue)
    {
        [value release];
        value = newValue;
        [value retain];
    }
}
```

This is for a `@property (nonatomic, retain)...`

The real magic is, that each time you set your instance variable (from in- or outside the object itself) you want to make sure, that you own the passed newValue (with retain), release the old value and set the new value.
So it is possible to set the instance Variable multiple times, without having to manually release the old one. Thats only a speed option :-)